# Mathematica running out of RAM while executing NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, memory, crash

I am playing with Mathematica to solve the 2D-wave equation with the code below:

```
tmin = 0; tmax = 1; xmin = -1; xmax = 5; ymin = -1; ymax = 1;
weqn = D[u[t, x, y], {t, 2}] == D[u[t, x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[t, x, y], {y, 2}];
ic = {u[0, x, y] == Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)],Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 2*x*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]};
sol = NDSolve[{weqn, ic}, u, {t, tmin, tmax}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01]
```

At some point in my computation, my laptop runs out of RAM and Mathematica quits the Kernel. Is there any way I can make Mathematica save the solution as to free up RAM and continue the computation up to greater time?

**Update** Regarding initial conditions.

Consider, for simplicity, the 1D-wave equation. The solutions are of the form $u(t,x) = f(x-t) + g(x+t)$, the former and the latter represent solutions going to the right and left, respectively. If we run the following code on Mathematica:

```
weqn = D[u[t, x], {t, 2}] == D[u[t, x], {x, 2}];
icn = {u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2], Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0};
DSolve[{weqn, icn}, u[t, x], {t, x}]
```

We get

```
u[t, x] -> 1/2 (E^-(t - x)^2 + E^-(t + x)^2)
```

As expected. But it is possible to pick the solution going to the right by setting $\partial_t u (0,x) = 2 x e^{-x^2}$. In fact, by setting

```
ic = {u[0, x] == Exp[-x^2], Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 2*x*Exp[-x^2]};
```

Mathematica gives

```
u[t, x] -> E^-(t - x)^2
```

And this completely describes the solution. However, when I solve the same equation with the same i.c. by using NDSolve, I get the bcart warning. But the numerical solution behaves exactly like the analytical solution.

I used the same reasoning to set the initial condition for the 2D-wave equation. It's a gaussian moving in the x-direction. In fact, for small times, this is what I'm getting.

So, even though there could be an issue with boundary conditions, I wanted to solve the equation in a larger grid in which the initial gaussian packet would not reach the boundary during my run.

I still would like to know if it would be possible to save the solution on the laptop's drive while NDSolve is still running.

Comment: You are trying to solve numerically wave PDE on square, but you did not supply boundary conditions? I am afraid to try your code, because I do not want to run out of RAM and have to reboot.   Strange that the code run. But try again with boundary conditions and see what happens.

Comment: Please notice the missing of b.c.s is a serious problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73961/1871 @Nasser Actually OP's code produces `bcart` warning, at least in _v11.3_.

Comment: Please see my edit. Moreover, what boundary conditions can I use to test this?

Comment: As already mentioned under [your last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197980/1871), you need e.g. ABC or PML to approximate b.c. at infinity.

Comment: Ignoring the warnings, from a fresh kernel,I get a solution with your code without a crash using a maximum of 4GB of memory (V12, Mac, 16GB RAM).

Comment: To do what you want, you could probably adapt the [`MonitorMethod` from this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html#41467666)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I decided to solve the 1d problem before tackling this one. I am still running into (different) problems https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199337/ndsolve-cannot-evolve-gaussian-wave-packet-with-small-width